# Check if new Database has been created on remote SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been tasked with building an alert on new database creation.

We have a central server that reaches out to all of our SQL servers and captures different metrics via linked servers.

I need to somehow capture a list of all databases on each server and store that list on my central server.  Then a couple times a day run a SQL Agent job that compares the current database list on the remote server to the database list on the central server.  And if a database has been added on the remote server or been removed send an e-mail.

I am just having a hard time putting the pieces together and was looking for any helpful information.  I would also be open to a different method if one would be more feasible.

Regards
gb

Comment: Create a server-scope DDL trigger for the `CREATE_DATABASE` and `DROP_DATABASE` [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx).  Within the trigger code, you could send a notification email.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have the need to maintain the list of db's?  If not, just use a server-scoped DDL trigger to generate an email whenever a db is created or dropped.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCreateDatabase 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
AS 
    DECLARE @Subj NVARCHAR(255) 
    DECLARE @MailBody NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Subj = @@SERVERNAME + ' - Database Created'
    SELECT @MailBody = 
        'TSql Command: ' + EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        'Login Name: ' + EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
        @from_address = 'From@Someone.com',
        @recipients = 'To@Someeone.com', 
        @Subject = @Subj,
        @body = @MailBody
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgDropDatabase 
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR DROP_DATABASE 
AS 
    DECLARE @Subj NVARCHAR(255) 
    DECLARE @MailBody NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Subj = @@SERVERNAME + ' - Database Dropped'
    SELECT @MailBody = 
        'TSql Command: ' + EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
        'Login Name: ' + EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
        @from_address = 'From@Someone.com',
        @recipients = 'To@Someeone.com', 
        @Subject = @Subj,
        @body = @MailBody
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I once had a maintenance database that kept track of the databases by using a RegisteredDatabases table. Then a SQL Agent job would run on a schedule and check to see if sys.databases drifted from what my maintenance database was aware of. The stored procedure would either throw an error causing the SQL Agent job to send an email via the alert system or simply remove the database from the list (usually only used when the sproc was manually run).

The below code was used in a specialized project of mine. You will need to take the pieces out of it that you want.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Configuration].[usp_RefreshRegisteredDatabases] 
    @Purge BIT = 0
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Vars
    DECLARE @PurgeDBList udt_DatabaseList

    --Populate new databases, if there are any
    INSERT INTO [Configuration].[RegisteredDatabases] (DatabaseName)
            SELECT  [Sdb].[name]
            FROM    [sys].[databases] Sdb
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Configuration].[RegisteredDatabases] Rdb ON [Sdb].name = Rdb.DatabaseName
            WHERE   Rdb.DatabaseName IS NULL

    --Throw error if database(s) no longer exist but the @Purge flag is set to 0.
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT   [Rdb].[DatabaseName]
                FROM     [sys].[databases] Sdb
                        RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Configuration].[RegisteredDatabases] Rdb ON [Sdb].name = Rdb.DatabaseName
                WHERE    Sdb.name IS NULL)
                AND @Purge = 0 
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Registered database(s) no longer exists. If any configurations are pointing to this database they will fail. Query Configuration.vwOrphanedDatabases for more details.',16,1)
        END 

    --Remove databases from the list where they don't exist anymore
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT   [Rdb].[DatabaseName]
                FROM     [sys].[databases] Sdb
                        RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Configuration].[RegisteredDatabases] Rdb ON [Sdb].name = Rdb.DatabaseName
                WHERE    Sdb.name IS NULL )
                AND @Purge = 1
        BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO @PurgeDBList (RegisteredDatabaseID, DatabaseName)
            SELECT   Rdb.DatabaseID, [Rdb].[DatabaseName]
            FROM     [sys].[databases] Sdb
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Configuration].[RegisteredDatabases] Rdb ON [Sdb].name = Rdb.DatabaseName
            WHERE    Sdb.name IS NULL

            EXEC [Configuration].[usp_PurgeAllReferencesToDatabase] @DatabaseList = @PurgeDBList        
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a list of servers already. loop through the list of servers querying sys.databases. Use dynamic SQL to generate the linked server query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS for this. The SSIS package could go out to the servers execute the following SQL -

```
USE master;
SELECT @@ServerName, NAME FROM sysdatabases;
```

and do a lookup against your central server that has the list of databases and flag the ones that do not exist in your database and insert them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with a PowerShell version.

```
 import-module sqlps
 DIR SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT\Databases | select Name
```

Change the localhost for each server, dump the list into memory and load into SQL for a permanent record. You could also do a quick compare to a master list.

Alternatively as you are already using linked servers, query

```
select @@servername, name from linkedserver.master.sys.databases
```

And compare to your master list.